# Register a service-worker in index.html file that's located in SRC folder - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

### Run service-worker from other folder

I'am trying to use service-worker to precache entire of PWA and i need to locate SW inside of SRC folder.

How can I run my SW from **public/index.html**?

I use create-react-app and i use google workbox to generate service-worker.

I try to import SW into App.js file, but I catch an error:

> 'importScripts' is not defined no-undef

```
importScripts(
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.0.0/workbox-sw.js"
);

const precacheManifest = []; 

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp("https://app.tessa.technology/api/"),
  new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst()
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp(
  "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
),
new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst()
);


 workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
```

- public

  - manifest.js
  - index.html
- SRC

  - JS
  - CSS
  - SW.js

Comment: What browser are you testing with thats producing this error?

Comment: i try Firefox and chrome with enabled option to run service worker offline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways.

1) Put your `service-worker.js` file in public directory.

2) Or, use the [workbox-webpack-plugin](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin). With this way the `service-worker.js` will be generate and imported automatically. This way is more recommended.